# Parâmetros entre páginas (ASP.NET Core / C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Olá, estou com uma dúvida na qual já pesquisei muito e não obtive nenhuma resposta concreta. Sou iniciante em C# e ASP.NET, me perdoem pela ignorância.

Tenho um projeto em ASP.NET Core MVC.

Nele tenho a Página A e a Página B.

Na Página A tenho um botão "Adicionar Item da Página B", no qual ao ser clicado, preciso que vá para a Página B carregando o ID da Página A.

Gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de se fazer isso sem usar JS.

Comment: a solicitação pra página B vai ser GET ou POST ? se for GET, passa o parâmetro na URL, `Controller/Action/{Parametros}` se for por post, pode usar um formulário...etc...

Comment: Vai ser um POST, acontece que esse botão ja está dentro de um formulário, posso ter um form dentro do outro? 

Pensei em de repente fazer usando RedirectToAction, más é GET, e como é um ID, fica fácil pro usuário manipular na URL

Comment: não sei se pode ter um form dentro do outro, mas não sei qual seria a utilidade disso, visto que vai sair da página...

Comment: Seria basicamente passar o parametro para a controller e da controller redirecionar para a Pagina B passando o ID da A por uma ViewBag se quiser posso montar um ex como resposta de um ex funcional

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver colocando no onclick do botão a seguinte função:

```
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")/'+$('#IdPai').val()"
```

Sendo assim, na Action do Controller eu recebo um id como parâmetro e dentro do método crio um novo objeto com o id em questão. Veja um exemplo de como ficou no controller

```
public IActionResult Create (int id = 0) {
    var Objeto = new ObjetoViewModel();
    Objeto.IdExterno = id;
    return View(objeto);
}
```